# IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 (Ultimate Edition) hangs my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: intellij-idea, ubuntu-18.04

I don't know why but sometimes my IDE hangs for some seconds, my settings are:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx2046m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine
-Dsun.tools.attach.tmp.only=true
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's a [known Kernel bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1872001). See also [a bug report in YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-2269).

The workaround is to downgrade kernel to **5.3.0-45** version. Check the linked issues for the other possible solutions.

The issue started to occur with **5.3.0-46** kernel update. IDE [thread dumps](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544899) will have something like this:

```
"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=0 tid=0x0 nid=0x0 runnable
     java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
 (in native)
    at java.desktop@11.0.6/sun.java2d.loops.Blit.Blit(Native Method)
    at java.desktop@11.0.6/sun.java2d.xr.XRPMBlitLoops.cacheToTmpSurface(XRPMBlitLoops.java:158)
    at java.desktop@11.0.6/sun.java2d.xr.XrSwToPMBlit.Blit(XRPMBlitLoops.java:366)
    at java.desktop@11.0.6/sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.blitSurfaceData(DrawImage.java:972)
    at java.desktop@11.0.6/sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.renderImageCopy(DrawImage.java:583)
    at java.desktop@11.0.6/sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.copyImage(DrawImage.java:86)
    at java.desktop@11.0.6/sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.copyImage(DrawImage.java:1043)
    at java.desktop@11.0.6/sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.copyImage(ValidatePipe.java:196)
    at java.desktop@11.0.6/sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.copyImage(SunGraphics2D.java:3325)
    at java.desktop@11.0.6/sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(SunGraphics2D.java:3368)
    at java.desktop@11.0.6/sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(SunGraphics2D.java:3310)
```

You will also see the following in the system logs (`dmesg` output):

```
[ 1177.290924] i915 0000:00:02.0: GPU HANG: ecode 11:1:0x85dffffb, in Xorg [1857], hang on rcs0
[ 1177.292069] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 for hang on rcs0
[ 1488.251067] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 for hang on rcs0
[ 1786.262953] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 for hang on rcs0
```

Comment: With kernel version 5.3.0-53 the issue seems to be resolved.